# Windows DNS explanation

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I'm managing a secondary server for DNS and the right click menu has three actions which confuse me

- Reload
- Transfer from Master
- Transfer new copy of zone from Master

These all sound suspiciously similar.  Could you explain what these different action mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reload: re-read the zone data stored locally on the server.
Transfer from Master: update the zone data with changes from the master server.
Transfer new copy: transfer a full copy of the zone data from the master server (not only the changes).

All of this only makes sense for standard master/slave zones; Active-Directory-integrated ones don't use a master/slave model and replication is managed by AD itself.